# Problem with a junk value in a member when using an empty default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I am trying to create a very basic class with a default constructor:

```
    class Point {
    public:
          Point() = default;//con 1
          explicit Point(double x): x_axis(x), y_axis(0){}//con 2
          Point(const Point &other) = default;
          ~Point() = default;
    private:
           double x_axis;
           double y_axis;
    }
```

When I try to use the default constructor in the `main()` function, it generates a random junk value for `x_axis`:

```
    Point p1;//generates random value
    Point p2{};//works as intended
```

Why is that? When I use the other constructor (con 2) like so:

```
    explicit Point(double x = 0): x_axis(x), y_axis(0){}
```

Both of them work as intended.

1. why, in the first try with no brackets, does it generate a random value, but `{}` worked, but in the second try they both work?
2. what is calling the default constructor with `{}`?

Comment: In C++, the philosophy is you only get what you pay for.  Your first attempt doesn't initialize anything because you didn't state to initialize anything.  This maybe not what you wanted, but C++ will not do this work unless you ask to do this work.  This allows programs that rely on the fastest of execution to be allowed to forego initialization, since that may impact the speed of such programs (I know it is rare to want this, but the programmer has this option).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the second constructor initializes the member variables with values while the first constructor leaves the member variables with indeterminate values.

Either do:

```
class Point {
public:
    Point() : x_axis{}, y_axis{} {} // instead of  = default
...
```

or

```
class Point {
public:
    Point() = default;

    // ...
private:
    double x_axis{};     // {}     or
    double y_axis = 0.0; // = 0.0  
};
```

Comment: could you elaborate please? I never saw initialization with {}, is this just for the default constructor so that the compiler won't mistake it for a function declaration?

Comment: @ReuvenGuetta No, it's for all initialization. See [uniform initialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#uniform-init)

Comment: @ReuvenGuetta It's a relatively new thing that you can initialize with `{}` instead of `()` avoiding some of the ambiguity with `()`. It's also relatively new that you can initialize member variables directly in the class. This acts as a fallback for any variable not initialized in the constructor (whichever one is used). This is a much recommended pattern now. Welcome to modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

> why in the first try, no brackets generated a random value but {} worked, and in the second try they both worked

In the first try when you wrote:

```
 Point p1; //this uses default constructor
```

Here the default ctor is used which just **default initializes** the data members `y_axis` and `y_axis`. Since these are built in types, they have indeterminate values.

In the second try when you wrote:

```
Point p2{}; //this is zero initailization
```

The above is [**zero initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) meaning the each data members is initialized to `0`.

---

Now, when you provided the following constructor:

```
explicit Point(double x = 0): x_axis(x), y_axis(0) //this is a default constructor
{
}
```

The above is a default constructor that initializes both the data members with `0` in the **constructor initializer list**.

Thus, this time when you write:

```
Point p1; //this uses the above provided default ctor
```

This time `p1` is default constructed using the default ctor that initializes both the data members to `0` and hence both `x_axis` and `y_axis` of `p1` will be initialized to `0`.